# SAS Macro Do Loop Issues

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

I have a very simple request.  Loop through a dataset, turning each observation into a macro variable, and then doing a comparison on that macro variable.  here's what my code looks like:

```
%do n = 1 %to &i2.;

data want;
set have;
%if _N_ = &n. %then %do;
call symputx("Var1",var1);
call symputx("var2",var2);
%end;
run;

data want;
retain FinalCount
set have;
where Variable1="&var1.";
by SomeVariable
if first.SomeVariable then FinalCount=0;
if final="FINAL" then FinalCount+1;
if Finalcount=&var2. then Final_Samples=1;
finalCount=FinalCount;
run;

%end
```

The part that is failing in the `_N_ = &n.` section.  I keep getting the error "Variable N has been defined as both character and numeric."  Basically I just need to set each observation as a macro variable once to do the next comparison, and then move on to the next guy.  So, if there's a better way of doing that, please let me know.  Otherwise, could you help me figure out why that comparison is not working?

Comment: The value of the macro variable N is a digit strings like 1, 23, etc. It will never be equal to the letter string \_N_.  Perhaps you want an actual IF statement instead of the macro statement there?

Comment: I think it should be ```if _N_ = &n then do;``` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could explain your larger problem then you might get a better answer that does not require you to convert your data values into macro variables. Converting values to strings and then trying to compare them again introduces a number of sources of errors.

To your question of how to set macro variables based on the Nth observation in a dataset,  try one of these.

If it supports the FIRSTOBS= and OBS= dataset options.

```
data _null_;
  set have (firstobs=&n obs=&n);
  call symputx("Var1",var1);
  call symputx("var2",var2);
run;
```

If the dataset supports direct access then use that.

```
data _null_;
  p = &n;
  set have point=p;
  call symputx("Var1",var1);
  call symputx("var2",var2);
  stop;
run;
```

If not then use an IF (not a macro %if).

```
data _null_;
  set have ;
  if _n_ = &n then do;
    call symputx("Var1",var1);
    call symputx("var2",var2);
    stop;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: All 3 fixes worked, thanks!.  Any idea why a macro %if was throwing off the comparison?

Comment: You need to understand what the macro processor does.  Your `%IF` was comparing the `_` as the first character of `_N_` to the first digit in the value of the macro variable `n`. SInce the latter is a digit and not an underscore the condition could never be true. To the macro processor `_N_` is just a three character string.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tom.  This doesn't make much sense to me, is there a website or source you could point me to?  I don't understand why using %if would make it take things literally as opposed to resolving the variable.

Comment: Read the manual on the macro processor https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/macro/index.html

Comment: Become your own macro processor. Replace the macro variables with their values.  Then apply the comparisons to the results. Then when you have finished with your macro logic see what SAS code you have generated and evaluate that.  `if _n_=5` will test if value of the automatic variable \_N_ is 5. `%if _n_=5` will test if the the string \_n_ is equal to 5. It cannot test the automatic variable \_n_ because the data step hasn't even been finished being written yet, much less started running.

Comment: Oh, the %if gets processed before the datastep because it's now part of the macro processor, so `_N_ `does not exist yet.  Thanks for the clarification, that makes sense now!